# WCF project reference to system.windows

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf

I have a WCF project and a silverlight 4 project.
I need to add a reference from the WCF to the silverlight project.
It requires system.windows dll, but I can't see it in my .Net tab under add reference.

How can I add it?

**EDIT:**

The errors I am receiving:

```
Could not locate the assembly "System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit, Version=4.0.5.0,    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35". 
Could not locate the assembly "System.Windows.Controls.Theming.Toolkit, Version=4.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35". 
Could not locate the assembly "System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit, Version=4.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35".
```

Answer (score 3):

If your missing references are happening on the Silverlight side, I am guessing you need to install the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/43528), as the assemblies you are missing are all toolkit assemblies.

If the toolkit errors are happening on the server-side, then you need to adjust your architecture to make sure you are not including UI controls in anything being passed via WCF.